# How to change table display attribute using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have a table that I have set to `display:none`. I want the table to change to `display:block` when a particular radio button is clicked. Using `onlick=""` within the radio tag didn't work so I implemented the following code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var adminbutton = document.getElementById('adminstatus');
    adminbutton.onclick = handler;
}

function handler() {
    account.getElementById('brokerform').style.display='block';
}
```

If I use an `alert()` within `handler()` it gets triggered with the appropriate radio button click, so I know the code block is getting executed. I can't figure out why the line in `handler()` does not make the table visible. I have also tried wrapping the table in a div and using the same style manipulation and it didn't work either.

Comment: Where do you set the variable `account`? Why not `document.getElementById('brokerform')`?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the Javascript console?

Answer (score 0):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ianwong/wq2jm2tw/)

```js
var adminbutton = document.getElementById('adminstatus');
adminbutton.onclick = show;

function show() {
    document.getElementById('brokerform').style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<table id="adminstatus">
    <tr>
        <td>adminstatus</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table id="brokerform" style="display:none;">
    <tr>
        <td>brokerform</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Why `account.getElementById('brokerform').style.display='block';`

Change to `document.getElementById('brokerform').style.display = 'block';`

Answer (score -4):

Try this...

```
account.getElementById('brokerform').show();
```

or this:

```
account.getElementById('brokerform').css("display", "block");
```

Comment: You are mixing up vanilla JS and Jquery.